# <ol> with numbers another color

Tags: html, css, colors, html-lists

```
<ol>
   <li>test</li>
   <li>test</li>
</ol>
```

will show as:

1. test
2. test

I want to have numbers coloured and text black!

I can edit the css, but I do not have access to the HTML.

Answer (score 125):

The [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#counters) gives an example of doing just this. Unfortunately, while it works on Firefox 3, it doesn't appear to work on IE7:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        ol { counter-reset: item; }
        ol li { display: block; }
        ol li:before {
            content: counter(item) ". ";
            counter-increment: item;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ol>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My only beef with the solution above is that any `<li>` items inside of a `<ul>` are now `1.` instead of a bullet.

Comment: @MartynChamberlin in a real-world implementation you would use selectors to specify where this styling should be applied.

Comment: @kdgregory Well, @feelinferrety updated his answer yesterday. It used to be that adding selectors to his solution broke it for `ol`, but I see that he fixed that problem. Rock on...

Comment: @MartynChamberlin @kdgregory another approach would be to use the child combinator, so `ol > li` and `ol > li::before` -- that way you only target this specific level of `li` elements.

Answer (score 36):

### Modern Approach (2021) - ::marker pseudo-element

The introduction of the `::marker` pseudo-element makes changing the color (and other styling) of numbers in an ordered list far simpler.

Example:

```
ol li::marker {
    color: red;
}
```

Modern browsers already support use of `::marker`: https://caniuse.com/css-marker-pseudo

We're at a point where older solutions (workarounds) are no longer necessary and most sites can be comfortable using `::marker` today.

Keep in mind that not all properties are available on the marker tag. See the MDN docs for more detail: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker

Comment: Wow, didn't think this would work with such complicated answers around it. Thank you for this simple answer.

Comment: This should be changed to the correct answer, as per 2021.

Answer (score 29):

Not sure if this works but i think it should:

```
<li style='color: red;'><span style='color:black;'>test</span></li>
```

**edit**
If you cannot edit the html then I'm afraid it's not possible. If you could add javascript to the HTML (once in the head) then you could do it like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 $('ol li').wrapInner('<span class="black"> </span>').addClass('red');
});
```

You will need the jQuery library for this.
Then in your CSS just set up a red and a black class with color:red/black declarations.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest inline-styles, but this is essentially the best option.

Comment: Inline styles was just to show how to do it, you should of course use classes as I do in the javascript example.

Answer (score 19):

Here's a solution that also wraps the text for each list item left-aligned below the first line (and not below the list number):

**HTML**

```
<ol class="GreenNumbers">
   <li>Long text that might wrap onto a second line.</li>
   <li>Long text that might wrap onto a second line.</li>
   <li>Long text that might wrap onto a second line.</li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
.GreenNumbers {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.GreenNumbers ol {
    margin-left: 2em;
}
.GreenNumbers li {
    counter-increment: count-me;
}
.GreenNumbers li::before {
    content: counter(count-me) ". ";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 0px;
    max-height: 0px;
    left: -1.3em;
    top: .05em;
    color: #008000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: This is the cleanest answer here! The css `counter()` has [97% support](http://caniuse.com/#search=counter), too. Spot on.

Comment: It's worth noting, however, that the [`direct-descendant` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#child-selectors) is probably best to use by default so that nested lists don't increment your counter. For example, `.GreenNumbers > li` would guard against that.

Comment: The good addition to this is `direction: rtl` for the boolet numbers.

Answer (score 7):

This should do what you're looking for:

http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/67894

HTML

```
<ol>
    <li>1 some text here</li>
    <li>2 some more text that can span longer than one line</li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
ol { list-style: none; padding-left: 2em; text-indent: -1em;}

li:first-letter { float: left; 
                  font-size: ??; 
                  color: white; 
                  background: orange; 
                  line-height: 1.0; }
```

Except you'll want to change the color and background according to your design.

This next one is overkill, but gives you a great deal of information on how to style lists:

http://print.wordpress.com/2006/02/22/css-beautifully-numbered-lists/

-Adam

Comment: This is good if old-browser (IE 6, etc) support is not needed.

Comment: If the user turns off CSS, it's going to show the number twice, which won't be very good for screen readers. Also, this will only work for single digit numbers. As soon as the list has more than 10 items, only the first digit is going to change colour.

Comment: This however creates additional content in the HTML which is often not wanted.

Comment: The link at the bottom, print.wordpress.com of the post has since gone down, please remove it

Answer (score 3):

@kdgregory 's code worked for me, but it affected my bulleted lists. I changed `li` to `ol li` to prevent the bullet items from being affected. Like so:

```
ol { counter-reset: item }
ol li { display: block }
ol li:before { content: counter(item) ". "; counter-increment: item; color: red; }
```

P.S. I also prefer to use uppercase in CSS for elements like `BODY` so I can easily distinguish it from classes `.body` and ids `#body`.

Answer (score 2):

From an answer to a [similar question](http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/35180) I found elsewhere:

> Just as a side note, CSS3 will allow easy styling of list markers with the 
>   ::marker pseudo-element.

But for now it looks like you'd have to add the `<span>` to your html.

Comment: Works in FF68+ Ch80+.

Answer (score 0):

too bad you can't edit the html... how about js?

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) { x[i].innerHTML ="<span>" + x[i].innerHTML + "</span>" }

// or with jQuery
$('.li').each(function(){this.innerHTML="<span>" + this.innerHTML + "</span>" })
</script>

<style>
li {color: #DDD;}
li span {color: black;}
</style>
```

if not, maybe a good-enough solution would be

```
ol {background-color: #DDD;}
li {background-color: white;}
```

Answer (score -1):

To expand a bit on what others said, as well as additional question clarifications, there is no built-in way of doing this from CSS w/o touching the HTML. If you are looking to keep the HTML as clean and semantic as possible, I would do the styling using javascript, probably with a library like jQuery, to adjust the DOM so that the css can be more effective.

I would caution, however, using color to convey info. I'm not sure what the purpose of the  colored numbers is, but using color to display information leaves colorblind users out of the loop and is a big no no for accessibility.

Answer (score -1):

**html**:

```
    <ol>
    <li>1 A long bullet here it is long to show how it behaves on a second line</li>
    <li>2 A long bullet here it is long to show how it behaves on a second line</li>
    <li>3 A long bullet here it is long to show how it behaves on a second line</li>
    <li>4 A long bullet here it is long to show how it behaves on a second line</li>
    <li>5 A long bullet here it is long to show how it behaves on a second line</li>
    </ol>
```

**css**:

```
ol { list-style: none; padding-left: 10px; text-indent:0px; margin-left:5px;}

ol li {color:#666;}

ol li:first-letter {color:#69A8DE; padding-right:5px; margin-left:-15px;}
```

Comment: `<li>` tag was creted especially for numbering, so disabling it - is the same, as put all items in `<p>` tag instead

Answer (score -1):

In CSS change the color of your ul li{ color: yourcolor}
In html put a span in the li with a class and give it another color. It works for any list-style that its not and image.

Comment: OP says: "I do not have access to the HTML"

Answer (score -4):

This is easy, as long as you don't want to assign different colours to different list item numbers. No HTML modifications necessary. Might not work in 100% of browsers though..

```
ol {color:red;}
ol li {color:black;}
```