# Nested list css styling

Tags: css, html-lists, nested-lists

I want to create css to generate the following nested list.

**1.** item1

- subitem
- subitem

**2.** item2

- subitem
- subitem

What I want is to modify the numbers (either bold or red). I searched in the internet but what I  [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488830/ol-with-numbers-another-color) was css for an ordered list. When I create a nested list with that css, what I obtain is extra numbers in place of the bullets. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CSS counter` only on `li`'s that are direct children of `ol` with this HTML structure and then change color and font-weight.

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: ol-counter;   
}
ol > li:before {
  counter-increment: ol-counter;               
  content: counter(ol-counter) ". "; 
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>item1
    <ul>
      <li>sub item</li>
      <li>sub item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>item2
    <ul>
      <li>sub item</li>
      <li>sub item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```